# Blur / Drop Shadow Effect Vector Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, blur, drop-shadow

I am start to learning adobe illustrator, I want to ask about making drop shadow / gaussian blur of an object in vector ( non bitmap / raster ) type. 
I found a file and want to use it for study material, but I confuse how / from where this shadow was made. 
I check the layers are only one object. But if I ungroup it the shadow was dissapeared.

Thanks for the answers and sorry for bad english :)

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as a "vector blur". It does not exist. Illustrator merely auto-generates **raster** images for blurs and glows.

Comment: ... but... `Effect > Stylize > Outer Glow` to apply it (which will auto-generate a *raster image*).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. After do some research I found that "blur" is an outer glow and it's a raster / bitmap. I am sorry if my question make you confuse. I just try to learn this software. I usually use corel draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]Blur and Drop Shadow are not same thing as the names are self explanatory.

If you look at 'Effect' panel you will see two groups of effect.
1- Illustrator effect
2-Photoshop effect

From 'illustrator effect' choose stylize-drop shadow.
From popup menu set your desired direction (X offset/y offset), opacity, color etc.

And if you want 'blur' go to effect-Photoshop effect-blur-Gaussian blur.

Comment: Ok, let says it blur effect, but in vector not raster / bitmap because. I cant find effect panel in illustrator window. I just need to know how that blur effect was made but in vector type of object ( shape / path / stroke )

Comment: what exactly you mean by  ''how that blur effect was made '' ... there i circled it. see now?? the ''EFFECT''

Comment: Here is  another answer---
Blur/Gaussian blur  uses a Gaussian function named after  Carl Friedrich Gauss, a German mathematician and physicist.

There are many algorithms to implement blur, one of them is called Gaussian Blur algorithm. Gaussian Blur is utilized to reduce the amount of noise in an image.
 If you want to know more kindly goggle '  Gaussian Blur theory'

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. After do some research I found that "blur" is an outer glow and it's a raster / bitmap. I am sorry if my question make you confuse. I just try to learn this software. I usually use corel draw.